# How can I find an element using xpath in this case?

Tags: angular, cypress

I have a div tag like this:

```html
<div id = "ID1">
 <div class="class1 class2 
 class3">A
 </div>
 <div class="class1 class2">B
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to get the element A by using

```
cy.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"class1.class2.class3")]').click()
```

But this is not able to click the element and gives the error of timed out.

How can I use xpath for this element?

Comment: Are you trying something complex on purpose? Because `cy.get('#ID1 .class3')` would be enough. And also, it's not maintainable. See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements for the best practices

Comment: Also could you please share the error you are getting after timeout?

Comment: @Wandrille Yeah I was trying to see if this can be done via the Xpath way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following Xpath syntax.

```js
cy.xpath(`//div[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2') and contains(@class, 'class3')]`).click()
```